# Highlight differences between two html strings

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I have 2 HTML strings with multiple subtle differences:

```
<tbody class="Expanded4" id="divisionG_area24_clubs"><!--<tr><th class='noBorderLeftRight'></th>--><th class="noBorderLeftRight" colspan="6"></th><th colspan="6"><table style="margin-bottom:auto;" width="100%"><tr><th class="noBorderTopLeft" style="width:auto;"></th><th class="Grid_top_blue Grid_Table" colspan="2">Membership</th><th class="Grid_top_blue Grid_Table" colspan="1">Goal4s</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="6">Education</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="2">Mem.</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="2">Trn.</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="2">Rn.|Lst.</th></tr><tr><th class="noBorderTopLeft" style="width:auto;"></th><th class="Grid_top_black_max Grid_Table">Base</th><th class="Grid_top_black_max Grid_Table">To Date</th><th class="Grid_top_black_max Grid_Table blue_border_right">Met</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Four Level 1 awards">1</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Two Level 2 awards">2</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Two more Level 2 awards">3</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Two Level 3 awards">1</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="One Level 4, Level 5, or DTM award">5</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="One more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM award">6</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 New members">7</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 More new members">9</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 Officers trained first training period">9a</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 Officers trained second training period">9b</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="1 Dues-renewal on time">10a</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="1 officer list on time">10b</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=01448795'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Advanced Speakers on the Hill"> <span class="redFont">01448795</span> Advanced Speakers on the Hill</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>29<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>30<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">2</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="3 Level 1s needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="Achieved">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="Achieved">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="3 New Members needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">7</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=02194262'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Inclusive Toastmasters"> <span class="redFont">02194262</span> Inclusivey Toastmasters</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>21<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>21<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">7</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 Level 1s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">5</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=02785335'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Club Toastmasters FrancoFun"> <span class="redFont">02785335</span> Club Toastmsasters FrancoFun</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>21<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>21<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">1</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 Level 1s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="Achieved">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">6</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=04437661'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Feel Good Toastmasters"> <span class="redFont">04437661</span> Feel Good Toastmasters</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>21<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>22<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">0</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 Level 1s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="3 New Members needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">6</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr></table></th></tbody>
```

and

```
<tbody class="Expanded4" id="divisionG_area24_clubs"><!--<tr><th class='noBorderLeftRight'></th>--><th class="noBorderLeftRight" colspan="6"></th><th colspan="6"><table style="margin-bottom:auto;" width="100%"><tr><th class="noBorderTopLeft" style="width:auto;"></th><th class="Grid_top_blue Grid_Table" colspan="2">Membership</th><th class="Grid_top_blue Grid_Table" colspan="1">Goals</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="6">Education</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="2">Mem.</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="2">Trn.</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="2">Rn.|Lst.</th></tr><tr><th class="noBorderTopLeft" style="width:auto;"></th><th class="Grid_top_black_max Grid_Table">Base</th><th class="Grid_top_black_max Grid_Table">To Date</th><th class="Grid_top_black_max Grid_Table blue_border_right">Met</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Four Level 1 awards">1</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Two Level 2 awards">2</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Two more Level 2 awards">3</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Two Level 3 awards">4</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="One Level 4, Level 5, or DTM award">5</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="One more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM award">6</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 New members">7</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 More new members">8</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 Officers trained first training period">9a</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 Officers trained second training period">9b</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="1 Dues-renewal on time">10a</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="1 officer list on time">10b</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=01448795'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Advanced Speakers on the Hill"> <span class="redFont">01448795</span> Advanced Speakers on the Hill</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>29<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>30<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">2</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="3 Level 1s needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="Achieved">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="Achieved">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="3 New Members needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">7</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=02194262'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Inclusive Toastmasters"> <span class="redFont">02194262</span> Inclusive Toastmasters</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>21<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>21<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">0</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 Level 1s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">5</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=02785335'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Club Toastmasters FrancoFun"> <span class="redFont">02785335</span> Club Toastmasters FrancoFun</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>21<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>21<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">1</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 Level 1s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="Achieved">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">6</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=04437661'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Feel Good Toastmasters"> <span class="redFont">04437661</span> Feel Good Toastmasters</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>21<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>22<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">0</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 Level 1s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="3 New Members needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">6</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr></table></th></tbody>
```

I'm trying to search for differences between the two strings. I need to return the second string, where any differences are highlighted using `<mark>` tags.

This is a bit hard to explain, so here are some examples:

If one string has the text `<span>This is a string</span>` and the second has `<span>Thiss is a string</span>`, I want to return `<span><mark>Thiss is a string</mark></span>`.
If another string has the text `<p>36</p>` and the second has `<p>3</p>`, I want to return `<p><mark>3</mark></p>`.

Note that the `<mark>` tag is inserted **after** the nearest `>` to the **left** of the difference, while the `</mark>` is inserted **before** the nearest `<` to the **right** of the difference.

I'm sure this is possible, but I can't seem to find a way to achieve this that works. This is what I have so far:

```
skew=0
prev_i = []
highlighted_area_info = my_second_html_string
diff = difflib.ndiff(my_first_html_string, my_second_html_string)
for i,s in enumerate(diff, start=0):
    if s[0]==' ':
        continue
    else:
        if i in prev_i:
             continue
        count_right = my_second_html_string[i].find('<')
        
        count_left = 0
        for a, b in reversed(list(enumerate(my_second_html_string))):
            if a < i:
                if b == ">":
                    break
                else:
                    count_left += 1
                
        highlighted_area_info2 = highlighted_area_info[:i-count_left+skew]
        highlighted_area_info2 += highlight_beginning
        highlighted_area_info2 += highlighted_area_info[i-count_left+skew:i+count_right+skew]
        highlighted_area_info2 += highlight_end
        highlighted_area_info2 += highlighted_area_info[i+count_right+skew:]
        skew += len(highlight_beginning)+len(highlight_end)
        highlighted_area_info = highlighted_area_info2
        prev_i = list(range(i-count_left+skew, i+count_right+skew))
print(highlighted_area_info)
```

Unfortionately, the `<mark>` and `</mark>` tags are inserted in incorrect positions, leading to issues like this: `<td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder"><mark>0</</ma<mark>rk>s</mark>pan></td>`
instead of `<td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder"><mark>0</mark></span></td>`, which is what I'm expecting.

I've spent days on this, but I'm still not sure what I am doing wrong, although something is obviously not right. My code is likely not utilizing the most efficient way to achieve my goal, either.

I need to have working code in a few days, so any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: maybe when you add `<mark>` and `</mark>` in text then you should add its length to position of next element. OR maybe you should use `print()` to see values in variables and text which you change to see if you use correct values. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see problem. OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: better create minimal working code with example data which makes problem and then we can copy and run it to test it and make changes (test ideas)

Comment: did you use `print()` to see what you have in variables? Check `i, s`. It shows strange things and you should check documentation for `ndiff()`. `ndiff()` needs list of lines (even if you have only one line) but you use string so it treats this string as list of chars and it compare single chars - and for every char it adds `<mark>`. If both files have the same structure and only different values in tags then I would rather use `beautifulsoup` or `lxml` to convert file to three and visit all nodes and compare text in nodes.

Comment: see module [xmldiff](https://xmldiff.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) - it seems better then `difflib`. It uses `lxml` and it works with XML and HTML (if all tags are closed in one tag ie. `<html>`) and it gives me `xpath` to node so I can use use it with `lxml` to access node and edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `print()` to test values in variables in your code and I found that you use `ndiff(string1, string2)` but it needs `ndiff(list_of_lines1, list_of_lines2)` - so it treats your strings as list of chars and it compares every char separatelly. This way it puts `<mark>` for every changed char - instead of puting one `<mark>` for full word.

I tried to change this using lists with single line `ndiff([string1], [string2])` and other changes but finally I resigned because it makes no sense. You would rather need to use `lxml` or `Beautifulsoup` to parse `HTML` to tree with `tags` as `nodes` and then compare `text` in `nodes`.

---

I found module [xmldiff](https://xmldiff.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) which uses `lxml` and it generates list of changes for two `XML` or `HTML`.

```
import xmldiff.main

all_changes = xmldiff.main.diff_texts(my_first_html_string, my_second_html_string)
```

Every `change` gives `xpath` so I use `lxml` to find node and replace `text` with `<mark>text</mark>`

It can find differen [changes](https://xmldiff.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#the-edit-script) but I needed only `UpdateTextIn` (when text is inside tag - ie.`<a>new text</a>`) and `UpdateTextAfter` (when text is after tag - ie.`<a>...</a>new text`

```
highlighted_tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(my_second_html_string)

for item in all_changes:

    highlighted_node = highlighted_tree.xpath(item.node)[0]

    if isinstance(item, xmldiff.actions.UpdateTextIn):
        highlighted_node.text = '' # remove
        highlighted_node.insert(0, lxml.etree.fromstring('<mark>' + item.text + '</mark>'))

    if isinstance(item, xmldiff.actions.UpdateTextAfter):
        highlighted_node.tail = '' # remove # has to be before addnext
        highlighted_node.addnext(lxml.etree.fromstring('<mark>' + item.text + '</mark>'))
```

After that I conver tree to HTML again

```
html = lxml.etree.tostring(highlighted_tree)

print(html.decode())
```

---

Minimal working example with data

```py
import xmldiff.main     # diff_texts
import xmldiff.actions  # UpdateTextIn, UpdateTextAfter
import lxml.etree

my_first_html_string = '''<tbody class="Expanded4" id="divisionG_area24_clubs"><!--<tr><th class='noBorderLeftRight'></th>--><th class="noBorderLeftRight" colspan="6"></th><th colspan="6"><table style="margin-bottom:auto;" width="100%"><tr><th class="noBorderTopLeft" style="width:auto;"></th><th class="Grid_top_blue Grid_Table" colspan="2">Membership</th><th class="Grid_top_blue Grid_Table" colspan="1">Goal4s</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="6">Education</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="2">Mem.</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="2">Trn.</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="2">Rn.|Lst.</th></tr><tr><th class="noBorderTopLeft" style="width:auto;"></th><th class="Grid_top_black_max Grid_Table">Base</th><th class="Grid_top_black_max Grid_Table">To Date</th><th class="Grid_top_black_max Grid_Table blue_border_right">Met</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Four Level 1 awards">1</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Two Level 2 awards">2</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Two more Level 2 awards">3</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Two Level 3 awards">1</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="One Level 4, Level 5, or DTM award">5</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="One more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM award">6</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 New members">7</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 More new members">9</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 Officers trained first training period">9a</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 Officers trained second training period">9b</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="1 Dues-renewal on time">10a</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="1 officer list on time">10b</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=01448795'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Advanced Speakers on the Hill"> <span class="redFont">01448795</span> Advanced Speakers on the Hill</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>29<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>30<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">2</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="3 Level 1s needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="Achieved">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="Achieved">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="3 New Members needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">7</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=02194262'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Inclusive Toastmasters"> <span class="redFont">02194262</span> Inclusivey Toastmasters</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>21<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>21<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">7</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 Level 1s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">5</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=02785335'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Club Toastmasters FrancoFun"> <span class="redFont">02785335</span> Club Toastmsasters FrancoFun</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>21<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>21<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">1</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 Level 1s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="Achieved">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">6</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=04437661'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Feel Good Toastmasters"> <span class="redFont">04437661</span> Feel Good Toastmasters</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>21<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>22<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">0</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 Level 1s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="3 New Members needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">6</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr></table></th></tbody>'''
my_second_html_string = '''<tbody class="Expanded4" id="divisionG_area24_clubs"><!--<tr><th class='noBorderLeftRight'></th>--><th class="noBorderLeftRight" colspan="6"></th><th colspan="6"><table style="margin-bottom:auto;" width="100%"><tr><th class="noBorderTopLeft" style="width:auto;"></th><th class="Grid_top_blue Grid_Table" colspan="2">Membership</th><th class="Grid_top_blue Grid_Table" colspan="1">Goals</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="6">Education</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="2">Mem.</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="2">Trn.</th><th class="Grid_Title_top_black grid_blue_border" colspan="2">Rn.|Lst.</th></tr><tr><th class="noBorderTopLeft" style="width:auto;"></th><th class="Grid_top_black_max Grid_Table">Base</th><th class="Grid_top_black_max Grid_Table">To Date</th><th class="Grid_top_black_max Grid_Table blue_border_right">Met</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Four Level 1 awards">1</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Two Level 2 awards">2</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Two more Level 2 awards">3</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="Two Level 3 awards">4</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="One Level 4, Level 5, or DTM award">5</th><th class="Grid_top_black" title="One more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM award">6</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 New members">7</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 More new members">8</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 Officers trained first training period">9a</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="4 Officers trained second training period">9b</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="1 Dues-renewal on time">10a</th><th class="Grid_top_black max22" title="1 officer list on time">10b</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=01448795'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Advanced Speakers on the Hill"> <span class="redFont">01448795</span> Advanced Speakers on the Hill</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>29<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>30<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">2</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="3 Level 1s needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="Achieved">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="Achieved">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="3 New Members needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">7</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=02194262'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Inclusive Toastmasters"> <span class="redFont">02194262</span> Inclusive Toastmasters</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>21<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>21<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">0</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 Level 1s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">5</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=02785335'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Club Toastmasters FrancoFun"> <span class="redFont">02785335</span> Club Toastmasters FrancoFun</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>21<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>21<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">1</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 Level 1s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="Achieved">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">6</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr><tr class="Grid_Top_Row club_gray" onclick="window.location.href='ClubReport.aspx?id=04437661'"><td class="Grid_Title_top5 min280 crop" title="Feel Good Toastmasters"> <span class="redFont">04437661</span> Feel Good Toastmasters</td><th class="Grid_Table_yellow"><span>21<span></span></span></th><td class="Grid_Table title_gray"><span>22<span></span></span></td><td class="Grid_Table x_light_gray blue_border_right"><span class="chart_table_big_numbers goalsMetBorder">0</span></td><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 Level 1s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 2s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="2 Level 3s needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="1 more Level 4, Level 5, or DTM needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="3 New Members needed">1</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="4 New Members needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="First Training Period Achieved">6</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="Second Training Period 4 needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goal" title="On-time dues-renewal needed">0</th><th class="Grid_Title_goalAchieved" title="On-time officer list Achieved">1</th></tr></table></th></tbody>'''

#my_first_html_string =  '''<html>test1 <p>325</p><div>This</div> testA</html>'''
#my_second_html_string = '''<html>test2 <p>3</p><div>Thiss</div> testB</html>'''

all_changes = xmldiff.main.diff_texts(my_first_html_string, my_second_html_string)

#old_tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(my_first_html_string)
#new_tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(my_second_html_string)
highlighted_tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(my_second_html_string)

for item in all_changes:
    #print('item:', item)
    #print('item.xpath:', item.node)
    #print('item.text:', item.text)
    #old_node = old_tree.xpath(item.node)[0]
    #new_node = new_tree.xpath(item.node)[0]
    #print('old node:', lxml.etree.tostring(old_node))
    #print('new node:', lxml.etree.tostring(new_node))
    #print('old text and tail:', [old_node.text, old_node.tail])
    #print('new text and tail:', [new_node.text, new_node.tail])
    
    highlighted_node = highlighted_tree.xpath(item.node)[0]
    
    if isinstance(item, xmldiff.actions.UpdateTextIn):
        print('changed text:', item.text)
        highlighted_node.text = ''
        highlighted_node.insert(0, lxml.etree.fromstring('<mark style="background:red">' + item.text + '</mark>'))

    if isinstance(item, xmldiff.actions.UpdateTextAfter):
        print('changed tail:', item.text)
        highlighted_node.tail = '' # has to be removed before `addnext`
        highlighted_node.addnext(lxml.etree.fromstring('<mark style="background:red">' + item.text + '</mark>'))
    
    print('---')

html = lxml.etree.tostring(highlighted_tree)
html = html.decode()
print(html)

with open('output.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Result:

[image]

---

The only problem is that sometimes old text and new text may have the same text but different numer of spaces, tabs, new lines and it is also treated as `change` - but rather it would be skiped (but this need additional code)

Comment: Thank you so much! This works amazingly well, and is much more simple than my code using difflib. I'm not really worried about different spaces, tabs, and newlines, so your example is sufficient.